# Change resolution on LS055R1SX03 2k screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, display

I bought the HDMI to MIPI LS055R1SX03 5.5 inch 2k IPS LCD module 2560*1440 from Aliexpress,
Plugged it, and used a configuration found on the internet to be able to see any image.

Surprisingly it worked perfect after putting the following configuration:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_timings=1440 0 50 10 35 2560 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 50 0 198000000 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=500000000
hvs_priority=0x32ff
max_framebuffer_width=1440
max_framebuffer_height=2560
framebuffer_width=1440
framebuffer_height=2560
framebuffer_depth=24
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
gpu_mem=192
```

The problem is that everything is so small it's unreadable. I guess it's because the resolution is too high for such a small screen.

I figured out that if the above is working configuration, so somehow we can deduce a lower resolution configuration.

I tried to decrease the resolution, putting half of the size of the recommended working resolution: 1280 X 720 @ 25Hz but no image shown. 
obviously something is missing, or maybe there is another way for me to see something...

Comment: What Pi? What happened when you just booted without fiddling with the config.txt

Comment: @Milliways it's a Pi3. After putting 720 1280 in all above configuration (instead of 1440 2560) the screen backlight started for a second, and then just black screen, like if it's not working.

Comment: @Milliways without playing with the config.txt the screen is just black, doesn't see anything